# Reading genesis config on GoLang

Tags: go-ethereum, golang, genesis, project-fork

In a custom fork of Ethereum my team is developing, we need to read a new config parameter from genesis block. At https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/cmd/evm/runner.go#L100 the code line:

```
gen := readGenesis(ctx.GlobalString(GenesisFlag.Name))
```

is supposed to read a config parameter from genesis block, right?

But what is ctx?, how to specify the flag name to GlobalString?

What goLang code would we need to read a given parameter, such as MyParameter from genesis block?

Is there any documentation about the go-ethereum code? Who did develop this code? Can I talk to him/her? Thx!

Answer (score 1):

By looking at it, go-ethereum is using the [urfave/cli](https://github.com/urfave/cli) package for reading and parsing command line arguments. You can specify a new cli argument [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/cmd/evm/main.go#L31).

[`readGenesis`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/cmd/evm/runner.go#L53) is simply unmarshalling the json from the genesis path into the [`Genesis`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/genesis.go#L47) type, which you can extend by adding your new properties there.

Comment: Thx! but I am not looking for a way to read command line arguments, but genesis parameters, not really from genesis.json but directly from genesis block 0